# using net-snmp.js to send and retrieve get requests to many devices at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, net-snmp

Im have a list of about 50 IP addresses (ip.array_agg) to poll in a loop. Problem is that the async nature of the module means that the returning results come back at random times in any order so I need to track the sessions somehow. How can I link the outgoing snmp get session requests with the returning results in the callback so that I can associate the varbinds (results) with the associated IP address? Is there an session id or something I can use to tag the sessions? Maybe it is possible via dgram? A code example would be great.

```
    var snmp = require ("net-snmp");
    var community = 'terminal';

    var oids = ["1.3.6.1.4.1.2509.8.22.2.1.1.5.4","1.3.6.1.4.1.2509.8.22.2.1.1.5.1"];
    for( var i = 0; i < ips.array_agg.length; i++){
            var ip = ips.array_agg[i];
            var session = snmp.createSession ( ip, community);
            console.log(session);

            session.get (oids, function (error, varbinds) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error ('session get error:', ip,  error);
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < varbinds.length; i++)
                    if (snmp.isVarbindError (varbinds[i]))
                            console.error (snmp.varbindError (varbinds[i]))
                    else
                            console.log ( ip, varbinds[i].oid + " = " + varbinds[i].value/100);
                }
            });
    }
```